# AMS: How to use collection serializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I mean how should the serializer be implemented to work with a collection?

From active model serializers documentation:

```
render json: @posts, serializer: PaginatedSerializer, each_serializer: PostPreviewSerializer
```

How should be the `PaginatedSerializer` implemented?

I did something like this:

```
@posts = Post.all
render json: @posts
```

And it worked OK and did not required nor some special collection serializer, nor the each_serializer.

So now I'm confused to why would you need a collection serializer.

Comment: If you have more about this subject, I'm interested !

Answer (score 1):

To start an answer about *"why would you need a collection serializer"*,

I have some controller methods that return "unsorted" lists like so:

```rb
[ {
 id: 2,
 collection_id: 3,
 text_choice: "Cover"
},
{
 id: 3,
 collection_id: 3,
 text_choice: "Remix"
},
{
 id: 4,
 collection_id: 4,
 text_choice: "Studio"
} ]
```

But I want to return these entries grouped by `collection_id` and respond a JSON like this:

```rb
[
{
 "3": [ {
  id: 2,
  text_choice: "Cover"
 },
 {
  id: 3,
  text_choice: "Remix"
 } ]
},
{
 "4": [ {
 id: 4,
 text_choice: "Studio"
} ]
}
]
```

(sorry for the formatting: doing it "blind" is kind of difficult for a sublime text user ;)  )

So I arrived at the conclusion that I needed to implement my own `CollectionSerializer` for this transformation.
But like you, I couldn't find any example; actually, you've given the most advanced answer there is for the moment !
I'll try to play with your start and probably create an issue on GH.

I'll update if I get anything...

**To anybody: feel free to help us if you know more than us !!**

Answer (score 1):

Without listing the serializers I don't see how you would get paginated results in your JSON data, although you could get some serialized data if you implemented a `PostSerializer` serializer.

The `CollectionSerializer` (`PaginationSerializer`) is a serializer that provides attributes for the entire results set providing paging data in the JSON results, such as number of pages and total records.

I saw an example `PaginationSerializer` in this [wiki page](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/howto/add_pagination_links.md). It's pretty generic, so it would for any model.

It sounds like you might already understand the PagePreviewSerializer part, but I'll cover that too just in case. It's is a serializer for deciding which attributes are displayed for each Post displayed on the page.

The PaginatedSerializer can be generated with `rails g serializer post` (assuming the model is called "post". Then you just need to rename it to PostPreviewSerializer and add extra attributes to the "attributes" definition depending on which attributes you want to show in the json. For example you might declare it with `attributes :id, :title, :content` if those are your attributes.

**Bonus comment**

I noticed when following the instructions in the wiki page that `PaginationSerializer` inherits from `CollectionSerializer`. This serializer didn't exist in my version of the AMS gem, but turns out it's just `ArraySerializer` renamed. So inheriting from `ArraySerializer` worked for me.